# How can I find number of arguments without using arguments property?

Tags: javascript

Given this code snippet how can I find the number of arguments past to the function from within the function without using the arguments property of myFunc.

```
function myFunc() {
    "use strict";
    ...
    var j;
    for (j = 0; j < myFunc.arguments.length; ++j) { 
    ...
      }
}

myFunc("some", "arguments", "here");
```

Comment: Just use `arguments.length`, not `myFunc.arguments.length`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the `.arguments` property of the function. You have access to an `arguments` variable that references the arguments object as well.

```
arguments.length
```

---

```
function myFunc() {
    var j; // -------v---- no function reference needed
    for (j = 0; j < arguments.length; ++j) { 
       // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: that was quick,  could you show me an example I'm very new to this.

Comment: @user1769839: I just updated with an example, but all you need to do is use the `arguments` identifier in the function. It's a free variable provided in every function invocation.

Comment: @user1769839: Some documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Comment: I'm sorry I left out that I'm doing this in strict mode, it won't pass jslint.

Comment: @user1769839: Strict mode should have no trouble with the `arguments` object reference, and I just did a quick test in jsLint, and it didn't have any issue either. The only strict violation would come from using the `func.arguments` property since that's not allowed in strict mode.

Comment: Thanks, I suspect you're right I'll have to test it out and get back.